# Add another IP address to a Bonding Interface

Tags: networking, fedora, rhel, bonding

I have a Linux network Bonding interface for two Ethernet interfaces (eth0 and eth1)

```
$ cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond0   
DEVICE=bond0  
BOOTPROTO=static  
ONBOOT=yes  
IPADDR=XX.XX.XX.XX  
NETMASK=255.255.255.0  
GATEWAY=XX.XX.XX.XXX
```

How i can add another IPADDR to this bonding Interface ?

Answer (score 7):

What you want is called an Interface Alias.

Based on the files you mention, I think you're on Fedora, Red Hat or similar.

Their [Interface Configuration Files Reference Guide](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/3/html/Reference_Guide/s1-networkscripts-interfaces.html) suggest you want a new file called `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond0:0` containing

```
DEVICE=bond0:0
IPADDR=XX.XX.XX.YY
```

I assume you also need the other entries, e.g.

```
BOOTPROTO=static
ONBOOT=yes
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=XX.XX.XX.XXX
```

Comment: Thank Mikel for your help i am using Ret Hat shall i add only these two lines you mentioned in the new file ???

Comment: I'm guessing you also want to specify `NETMASK` and `GATEWAY`.  And the docs say DHCP is not supported, so you may need `BOOTPROTO` too.

Comment: Do i need to restart anything after creating this file ?

Comment: I'd try `ifup bond0:0` first.  If that doesn't work, try `/etc/init.d/network restart`.

Comment: Welcome!  Please try it and let us know if it works.

Comment: Thanks Mikel its working great, that is exactly what i want thanks for your help